# Check if page contains external JavaScript using python

Tags: javascript, python

I tried following,

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://www.ebay.in')
print (response.status_code)
print (response.content)
print response.content.find('tracker.js') # it returns nothing
```

Basically I want to check if page contains a script with src attr = tracker.js

Comment: Page that you trying to inspect don't contain any script tag. it's not event html page.

Comment: @Arnial yes...page contains tracker.js